# MySql, how to select not repeated values in 3 columns

Tags: mysql

I have tried group by col1,col2,col3, but does not work because all values of the 3 columns cannot be repeated and cannot be equals other.

**Table representation:**

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| col1   | col2   | col3   |
+--------+--------+--------+
| value1 | value3 | value5 |
+--------+--------+--------+
| value1 | value2 | value1 |
+--------+--------+--------+
| value3 | value1 | value3 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

I need select values not repeated

*That table has 1+ million rows, performance is important when construct the query*

Thank you so much!

Comment: what do you mean *how to select not repeated values in 3 columns* ?

Comment: give us a sample of expection

Comment: If performance is important, construct a table of 3million + rows, and 1 column instead

Comment: @BasilBattikhi see the edit

Comment: Value9 is not repeated

Comment: @Strawberry it is about queries and not table scheme

Comment: ok make a simple `where` 

`where col3 != col2  and col2!=col1 and col3!=col2`

Comment: Trust me. It's all about schema.

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I'd like to get unique values that would not be repeated in another column.

Comment: Yep what is the problem with my query which i give you ?

Comment: @Strawberry You are wrong, the big problem is my english, I can't explain correctly, that table is a curriculums table with area1, area2, area3

Comment: If you had another row value1/value5/value3 should this be excluded from your results together with the row value1/value3/value5

Comment: @BasilBattikhi Your query in action:  SELECT area1, area2, area3 FROM `curriculums` where area3 != area2 and area2 != area1 and area3 != area2, its returns repeated values

Comment: what do you mean by repeated value ? it's completely different value at a row

Comment: A database table is NOT a spreadsheet. See normalisation and fix your schema accordingly. Your English is just fine. It's your understanding of relational data which is lacking.

Comment: @Strawberry let me know if you really understood what does he mean by repeated value ?

Comment: @Strawberry I need select only the areas and not the curriculums, with no repeated areas

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I really understood - even though there are no areas or curricula here

Comment: can you tell me what does he mean

Comment: The op wants only rows with non-repeated values. So 1-2-3 is valid , and 1-2-1 is not. In a properly normalised environment, this kind of problem is trivial.

Comment: @BasilBattikhi See my answer, now it works correctly, but I'm not sure if UNION is good for performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(select distinct col1 from table) UNION DISTINCT (select distinct col2 from table) UNION DISTINCT (select distinct col1 from table)`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to build the query with non-repeated values.

```
(select distinct col1 from table) 
UNION DISTINCT (select distinct col2 from table) 
UNION DISTINCT (select distinct col3 from table)
```

Comment: This query does not give the result you asked for - it returns unique areas 1,2,3,5

Comment: @P.Salmon Sorry, my english is not good to explain correctly what I want, but I wrote "cannot be repeated and cannot be equals other"

Comment: this query will not give you the result you are looking for

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I need only the unique values of the 3 columns and not necessarily that all 3 columns are listed.

Comment: @Mystic That was my answer which I deleted when you added the example output (where you specified that you want 3 different columns).

Comment: @Mystic OK, I undeleted it.